# Finding set of functions

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory

$ f\left(u,v\right)=u^{2}+3v^{2} $

$g\left(x,y\right)=\begin{pmatrix} e^{x}cosy  \\ e^{x}siny \end{pmatrix}   $

How do I determine sets of $f\left(\mathbb R ^{2} \right)$ and set of $g\left(\mathbb R ^{2} \right)$ ?

I determine that f represent elliptic paraboloid and g represent circle, but how to write their sets?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I don't quite understand your question. To me e.g. $f(\mathbb R^2)=\{x\in\mathbb R\,|\,x>0\}$ but you could consider alternative definitions for e.g ellipses or parabaloids.

Comment: I have to express/write set of each function.

Comment: Perhaps you could give me an example of what you mean by the set of a function? For example what do you mean by the set of say $h(x)=x+y$.

Comment: I really dont know to answer what is set of that function, because I just dont understand how to find it. But here is for example one example from book: $h\left(r,\phi\right)=\begin{pmatrix} rcos\phi \\ r sin\phi \\ r \end{pmatrix}$  


$h\left(\mathbb R ^{2} \right)=\left\{ \left(x,y,z\right)\in \mathbb R   x^{2}+y^{2}=z^{2}    \right\} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some comments, I think I understand what you mean so do please correct me if I'm wrong. Let's first have a definition.

If $h:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ is a function and $A\subset \mathbb R^n$ then
$$h(A) = \{ h(a)\in \mathbb R^m \,|\, a\in A\}$$

Then using your definitions of $f,g$ above we have:

$$f(\mathbb R^2) = \{x\in \mathbb R \,|\, x\ge0\}$$

$$g(\mathbb R^2) = \mathbb R^2 - \{(0,0)\}$$

Can you prove these?

E.g. That $f(u,v)\ge 0$ for all $u,v$ and that if $x>0$ then there is some $u,v$ such that $f(u,v)=x$

Comment: First I understand I think.. but second is confusing? How to get that or prove that?

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic are you asking about the value I gave for $g(\mathbb R)$ or about the second part of the last paragraph?

Comment: I am asking for g(R)?

Comment: What can you set $x,y$ to be such that $g(x,y) = 0$? If I give you a point $(u,v)\ne(0,0)$ can you find some $x,y$ such that $g(x,y)=(u,v)$? This is equivalent

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure are you doing this like f and g are separate examples. There is no connection between f and g. Every function is by itself and I should find set of eacy separately. 
Anyway, should I just put  e^xcosy=0 and e^xsiny=0?

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic I definitely am treating them separately, I just used some of the same letters. The equation you gave is exactly the one you must show has no solutions to show that $g(\mathbb R)\subset \mathbb R^2 -\{(0,0)\}$

Comment: One more question, I dont understand what excatly means R^2-{0,0}. Can you put that shortly in words?

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic it means all of $\mathbb R^2$ except for the origin